# Error when running JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

I have added the using statement to the class I am running:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
```

And I am referencing the Newtonsoft.Json.dll in the same project.

I get no compile-time errors. But I do get a run-time one. I cant even do simple code like this (the hello doesn't show up before crashing):

```
        public void Main()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("hello");
            JObject j = new JObject();
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

I get the following error:

> DTS Script Task has encountered an exception in user code: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

With the following StackTrace:

> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>      at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()

Anyone know what this might be causing this?

Comment: that's the stacktrace, but not the exception.

Comment: Ah.  "DTS Script Task has encountered an exception in user code:  Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

Comment: can you show more of your implementation?

Comment: there are something else wrong in your code.

Comment: If I comment out the JObject line, everything runs fine (hello shows up and all).

Comment: Is there an [`InnerException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.innerexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?  Can you share the full `ToString()` value of the exception?